# Square v2 Server Error

Tags: square-connect

I am testing with the v2 C# payment example.
https://github.com/petespatio/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2/csharp_payment/PaymentExample

When i run locally everything works properly and i can actually create a payment.

When i try to run on my website (1and1 hosted), i get 
error calling charge: unable to connect to the remote server

Does anyone know what has to be done to allow this connection?

Regards

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your hosting. Are you able to make other outbound requests? Do you have some firewall or networking rules set up for your hosting?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pining the server you are connecting to? That's a good place to start. Try:

```
ping connect.squareup.com
```

To see if you can connect at all. If you can't ping the server, it might be a firewall issue on your server.

1&1 has information about setting firewall rules on their hardware firewalls for their dedicated linux servers here:

https://help.1and1.com/servers-c37684/dedicated-server-linux-c37687/system-security-c37699

and information on setting firewall rules for their cloud servers here:

https://www.1and1.com/cloud-community/learn/networking/firewall/

Hope this helps!

Comment: When i request the nonce, this works. When the charge is called this fails at the _transactionsApi.Charge. What specifically is the .Charge call trying to access?

Comment: The default.aspx.cs file has a place holder for _locationId...you need to fill that in for .charge method to work.  Look at the comments where is says _locationId = "REPLACE_ME". Also need an access token. Details here: https://github.com/petespatio/connect-api-examples/blob/master/connect-examples/v2/csharp_payment/PaymentExample/Default.aspx.cs

Comment: The request for the nonce is a request to the html form that is hosted on your server...so this is why you aren't having any connection issues there, I think.

Comment: and here's the details of the actual API endpoint that you would be connecting to. https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-charge

Comment: I just heard back from Square and transaction requests need the following - Host is: connect.squareup.com and Port: 443.

Comment: After all this interaction from 1and1 they tell me –
“Please also take note that your current package is Shared Hosting, meaning no access at the backend of the servers. Only Server packages, since it is your own server.”

Could anyone recommend hosts where it is possible to connect to connect.squareup.com? I am programming the website with .net

This application is to take payments for a local neighborhood pool and can’t afford a server package.

I thought I would be able to create a firewall entry with my current 1and1 website……